How to Combine Cross-Validation Error and Ensemble Prediction Variance in Machine Learning?
I am working on a machine learning project where I use an ensemble model (Random Forest) and I want to accurately represent the prediction uncertainty. Specifically, I want to combine the cross-validation error (e.g., RMSE) and the ensemble prediction variance to create a single measure of prediction uncertainty.
From my understanding, the cross-validation RMSE gives an estimate of the model's generalization error, while the ensemble variance represents the internal disagreement among the models in the ensemble.
I considered representing it with the following formula, but I am not sure if it is mathematically correct.​
$$
\text{Total Uncertainty} = \sqrt{\text{RMSE}^2 + \sigma_{\text{ensemble}}^2}
$$
​
